# mouse - x and y from the plane but why?

Tags: javascript, three.js

i will have a grid like this threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_voxelpainter and then when i click on a point i can do every thing i want. I just can't get it done :/

my vars

```
var onmouseclick;

var planex = 16000;
var planey = 16000;
var rasterx = 100;
var rastery = 100;
var waterGeometry;
var planeMaterials;
var watermaterial;
var waterplane;
var mouse;
```

then my function who i build the plane for the mapp

```
buildmapp = function () {
    //waterunderground  
    waterGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(planex, planey, rasterx, rastery);
    planeMaterials = [
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('ocean.jpg'),
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            wireframe: false
        }),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('ocean.jpg'),
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            wireframe: false
        }),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('ocean.jpg'),
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            wireframe: false
        }),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('ocean.jpg'),
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            wireframe: false
        }),
    ];
    watermaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(planeMaterials);
    waterplane = new THREE.Mesh(waterGeometry, watermaterial);
    waterplane.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    waterplane.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
    scene.add(waterplane);
}
```

then my mouseclick function. here the coordinates should come out from mouse - plane.x or y.
Only I can't find any guidance on how to do it.:/

```
//
onmouseclick = function () {
    mouse = new THREE.Vector3();
    window.document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        mouse.x = ((e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1);
        mouse.y = (e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 - 1;
        console.log(mouse.x, mouse.y, 'clicklockation', );
        // mouse - x and y from the plane but why ? 
    });
}
```

```
//gameprocess
update = function () {};
render = function () {
    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
GameLoop = function () {
    render();
    update();
    steuerung_tastatur_camera();
    onmouseclick();
    requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop);
};
//first build all object
buildobj();
```

Can someone help me or give me a guide or approach to what I need to look at?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is your problem? You don't know how to get the MouseX and MouseY on click event?

Comment: Do you want to know which tile of the grid is clicked? See [`Raycaster`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster)

Comment: Currently I only calculate my coordinates of the canvas on the screen. But I want to find out what the coordinates on my map are when I click on them. So I can move my object to these coordinates. I know how to move it there. but I don't know how to find out what the current position is on the map (waterplane) I clicked on.

Comment: @Rabbid76 i think that it is . I'll try it out tonight and see if it works.

Comment: i will have a grid like this https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_voxelpainter and then when i click on a point i can do every thing i want. I just can't get it done :/